# Do C & C++ compilers optimize comparisons with function calls?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, complexity-theory

Do C and C++ compilers generally optimize comparisons with functions?

For example, [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/size/) suggests that the `size` function on std::lists in C++ can have a linear complexity O(N) in some standard library implementations (which makes sense for a linked list).

But in that case, if `myList` is a huge list, what would something like this do?

```
    if (myList.size() < 5) return 1;
    else return 2;
```

Would the size() function find and count all N list members, or would it be optimized to short circuit after finding 5 members?

Comment: If it did `size()` the long way figuring out that stopping after 5 is a good idea is incredibly difficult for a compiler to do.

Comment: There's potentially scope for this if it inlines `size` but I think it's a long-shot to spot that it can break out of a loop that's incrementing a counter.

Comment: I would not really worry. While the C++03 standard did not require O(1) complexity for `size()`, it did *recommend* it, and it is simple to implement. I would be surprised if your implementation did not track the number of elements in the container (you can check this easily by reading the `<list>` header.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The size() function was more of an example, really.

Comment: @WanderNauta: The problem with wanting to ask a general question and asking a particular one is that you will get answers to the particular one. If the question is in general, the answer is that the compiler cannot do it in most cases. The case of a `size()` on a list is a particular case in the sense that being a template the compiler has the definition of the function and with that there is *some* remote chance that it could figure it out. In general, the compiler has no access to the definition of the functions and the chances of optimizing that are much harder.

Comment: So you're saying that the compiler *does* do this for your 'own' code, even if the function is not inlined?

Comment: Just the opposite, even with inlining there are very few chances, without it, forget it, the function has to run to completion before the comparison can be done

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Theoretically the possibility exists if `size()` was inlined, but to perform the optimization the compiler would have to

1. Detect that you are testing specifically a "less than" condition
2. Prove that the loop (assume one exists for the purposes of this discussion) results in a variable increasing monotonically
3. Prove that there are no observable side effects from the loop body

That's a big bunch of things to count on IMHO, and it includes features which are not "obviously useful" in other contexts as well. Keep in mind that compiler vendors have limited resources so there has to be really good justification for implementing these prerequisites and having the compiler bring all the parts together to optimize this case.

Seeing as even if this is a perf issue for someone *the problem can be easily solved in code*, I don't feel that there would be such justification. So no, generally you should not expect cases like this to be optimized.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would the value have to increase monotonically?

Comment: @WanderNauta: Because if it didn't, there would be no choice but to perform all iterations to determine whether the final value was less than 5.

Comment: Actually, it's not that bad. List length counting isn't that complex. And I know that modern optimizers even take advantage of UB on signed integer overflow to determine whether a series of increments leads to a monotonically increasing variable. (`unsigned` does not since `UINT_MAX+1` < `UINT_MAX`).

Answer (score 11):

Actually, in C++11, `std::list` is optimized and `size()` is returned in constant time.

For C++03, `size()` indeed operates in linear time, as it needs to count the elements each time.

> Would the size() function find and count all N list members, or would it be optimized to short circuit after finding 5 members?

Never seen this sort of optimization happening in practice. While it's certainly legal, I doubt there's any compiler that actually implements something like this.

Comment: Just as a side remark, similar code in a functional programming language, such as Haskell, will only expand till the required depth.

Comment: @Jaywalker: I am not as sure as you are. You need to create a `longer-than` method for this me thinks.

Comment: I'm staying out of this, until I saw the tag on SO I didn't know what Haskell was. I did StandardML in college.

Comment: @Jaywalker: I don't think GHC (the main optimizing Haskell compiler) will do this optimization. IIUC, it does separate compilation instead of inlining `length`.

Comment: In C++ the optimization could be done with hideous operator overloading for the `<` operator.....

Comment: @R.. Really? I mean usually you'd expect the `size()` function to be completely executed before `<` is even called. But then I long given up assuming there's any feature in C++ that doesn't exist ;)

Comment: @R.. How would that work? Wouldn't you have to return an object convertible to an integer that implements `<` from your size function, and the actual `size()` logic would be in the `<` or `>` overloads?

Comment: @Jaywalker As of now, `length xs < k` will traverse the entire list in GHC and I know of no implementation that shortcuts it. You'd get shortcutting with `genericLength xs < k` and a suitable lazy number type. Or with a rewrite rule `forall k xs. length xs < k = if k < 1 then False else null (drop (k-1) xs)`, but that'd be your own doing, not the compiler's. And it would change the behaviour for `length (1:2:undefined) < 2` for example, that's why the compiler can't provide it.

Answer (score 2):

The myList.size() function itself has no way to be compiled for the purpose you're using it for, so it will determine the entire size. In order to get the optimization you're suggesting, you would need a dedicated predicate function instead of the general `size()`, something like `bool sizeLessThan(int);`.

Comment: But in theory, this is an optimization the compiler could observe.  The question is, does this sort of thing occur in practice?

Comment: If the compiler can prove that the rest doesn't matter it's perfectly entitled to not bother so long as the observable behaviour is correct. It's theoretically possible for a compiler to prove this, just a little tricky in practice.

Comment: Sure it's possible but to get this would require something non-general. You have to expect that (in the general case), code for things like this will either be in a library or at least a different object, and thus linked in a generic manner (eliminating the likelyhood of such specialized optimizations).

Answer (score 2):

**NO** You are asking if the compiler can make a function behave differently depending on how its results are used. This could only potentially be done for inline functions where the caller and the function will be compiled together at the same time. It seems quite a stretch for anything beyond that.